# Micrometer Tracing with Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-micrometer

Let's say a request landed at the backend and we got the traceid. Now for some reasons, we need to push a message to the rabbit and that message will be read after a few minutes. How can I do that processing in that same traceid.

That message sent has a field in which we preserved the previous trace and span id.

We are using Spring 3 with micrometer.

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a trace is meant to cover processing that is scheduled for later execution in an event-based system.

In this case, you should consider creating a different trace in the rabbitMQ message processing but [Link to the previous span](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/182): both spans aren't technically parent/child but a Link can materialize this relationship.